# How do I implement negative numbers into this binomial coefficients method?

Tags: java, binomial-coefficients

```
private long binomial(int n, int k) {
    if (k == 0 || k == n) {
        return 1;
    } else if (k > n) {
        return 0;
    } else if (0 < k && k < n) {
        return binomial(n - 1, k - 1) + binomial(n - 1, k);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hi, does anyone know how I can implement negative numbers into the method I've got so far? The arguments which aren't satisfied are; k<0 , n=0 , n<0. I'm not sure how to implement these so I've placed 'return 0' as a placeholder.

Comment: What do you want to return?

Comment: The correct value/formula for each case. I'm not sure what the formula is for returning when k<0 etc.

Comment: Are you asking for the formula in the post?

Comment: Not in the original but I guess that's what I need to a degree. From the link below, if I'm reading it correctly, returning 0 is correct?

Comment: Then you could possibly close the question by accepting that answer. Ideally, posting a link as an answer is not acceptable and asking for a formula too is not considered as an ideal question on SO.

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new to SO. Guess I just needed clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram has an article discussing what happens when the numbers are negative:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html

[Cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y33P.gif)

Comment: This is not an answer. Please avoid posting links as answers.

Comment: Sorry, I understand why it is not a good enough answer, but what is stopping me from just copying and pasting from the website? I thought I was doing a service by at least providing the source?

Comment: Yes. Ideally, your answer is supposed to be a comment. Since you don't have enough reputation to comment, you should avoid posting answers like this to maintain your reputation so that you get the privilege to comment. Don't worry. Downvotes indicate that your answer is not qualified enough to appear here. No offence.

Comment: Okay, Thanks! It appears the OP found it useful to a degree, though.